# Cannot get a sum from a for loop

Tags: java, variables, for-loop

Here is my code:

```
public void checkOut() {   
    double sum;
    System.out.println("Checking out items ..."); 
    for (int i = 0; i < purchases.length; i++) {
        sum =+ purchases[i].getPrice();
        System.out.println(purchases[i].getDescription() + "/" + purchases[i].getPrice());
    }
    System.out.println("Amount due: " + "$" + new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(sum)); 
}
```

When I compile it I get this error:

> The local variable sum may not have been initialized.

Alternatively when I change the sum line to `double sum = sum + purchases[i].getPrice();`

I get the following error:

> sum cannot be resolved to a variable.

Its basically a method that takes the list of items placed in a shopping basket; prints the items and their individual price, then finds the total price (sum) of the items.

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 9):

Just initialize your variable:

```
double sum = 0.0;
```

In Java, a local method variable **must** be initialized before being used. In this case, you have just declared but not initialized your `sum` variable.

Note that the error is pretty descriptive: *The local variable `sum` may not have been initialized.* (emphasis mine).

> Alternatively when I change the sum line to > `double sum = sum + purchases[i].getPrice();` I get Error: *sum cannot be resolved to a variable.* (emphasis and syntax/grammar fixes mine).

This is because your `sum` variable is now inside the scope of the `for` loop and you're using it outside, which is wrong. The compiler is telling you that the `sum` variable has never been declared before so it can't use it.

This was the problem (template only):

```
for(...) {
    double sum = ...
}
//the compiler will complain asking what is this sum variable?
System.out.println(sum);
```

As stated in [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16534797/1065197), there is an error in your addition code. Fixing all that, your code will look like this:

```
public void checkOut(){   
    double sum = 0.0;
    System.out.println("Checking out items ..."); 
    for (int i = 0; i<purchases.length; i++) {
        sum += purchases[i].getPrice();
        System.out.println(purchases[i].getDescription() + "/" +
            purchases[i].getPrice());
    }
    System.out.println("Amount due: " + "$" +new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(sum)); 
}
```

Comment: +1 for giving the correct answer with detailed explanations in just 1 minute. I wonder why the OP is "sleeping"...

Answer (score 4):

Your variable `sum` needs to be initialized (0 is fine; same bytecode as 0.0), but you also have a serious error that your compiler is hiding from you. You do not mean to say "sum =+"

Instead, use `sum +=` because that is the correct addition assignment operator.

Note that `+=` will also do type conversion so it is actually better than just doing a = a + b. (That's a great defense for students whose teachers don't like "arcane" code like `+=`, besides the fact that the statement a = a + b just looks so horribly wrong mathematically.)

Comment: Hi Joseph, this is more of a comment than an actual, complete, standalone answer to the question. Consider removing this and posting this as a comment under the appropriate post, or you could [edit] the post to make it more complete.

Comment: Sorry, I was posting from a slow connection and by the time I submitted it the other comments about += were there.

Comment: You edits make it better. It is helpful, and you provide an explanation as to why. Nice edits!